# 4 Vertex Cover Problem is not NP Complete why?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, computability, np-complete

With Given Graph $G$ why finding that $G$ has a vertex cover of at most $4$ is in $P$ and Not in NP Complete. it means there us poly-time algorithm for this problem !!?

Comment: How many subsets of 4 vertices can you try?

Comment: Which is bounded from above by $n^4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your graph has $n$ vertices, there are $O(n^4)$ possible subsets of $4$ vertices. Given one such subset, it is easy to check if it is a cover in $O(n^2)$ operations, by inspecting every edge and verifying whether it has an endpoint in the given subset.

Thus, in $O(n^6)$ operations we can check all possibilities.

Comment: The number of edges in a graph of $n$ vertices is $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Yes. I encourage you to check yourself.

Comment: There is no need to enumerate all $O(n^4)$ 4-tuples in a single list. Just check vertices $v_i, v_j, v_k, v_{\ell}$ for $\ell > k > j > i$ with a 4-nested for-loop.